# MongoDB - Mongoose: document structure/architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a relatively simple question, however, I keep getting stuck, over and over again. I think this is the fourth time I have tried to re-structure my documents to try and get the desired result.

I want to create a database in mongoose with the following structure:

**A *User* has many *groups*, *posts* and *comments*. The *groups*, *posts* and *comments* all belong to a *User*. A *post* can belong to many *groups*, or none. And a comment belongs to a certain *post*.**

Here is what I have so far:

**UserSchema**

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        username     : String,  
        created: {type:Date, default: Date.now} 

    }

});
```

**PostSchema**

```
var PostSchema   = new Schema({
    url: String, 
    highlighted: String, 
    comment: String, 
    image: String, 
    timeStamp: String, 
    description: String, 
    title: String,
    created: {type:Date, default: Date.now}, 
    private: Boolean, 
    favorite: Boolean, 
    readlater: Boolean, 
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    comments: [{
        text: String,
        postedBy: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    }], 
    groups: [{
        name: String,
        postedBy: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    }]
});
```

**groupSchema**

```
var GroupSchema = Schema({
    name    : String, 
    created: {type:Date, default: Date.now},
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Although I may be wrong on this assumption, I think I have the post to user and comment to post relationship just the way it should be. Please correct me if I am wrong. The main problem I am having right now is with my group to post relationship. Currently, there is no relationship at all. As far as I can, it is almost as if the group belongs to the post, instead of the other way around. The only other way I can think to structure the group would be like so:

```
var GroupSchema = Schema({
        name    : String, 
        created: {type:Date, default: Date.now},
        postedBy: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }, 
        posts: [{
            title: String, 
            Url: String,
            comments: [{
                text: String
            }]
            etc....
        }]
    });
```

The only problem I can see in the structure above is that the post will be required to be part of a group, which I want to be optional. So as far as I can tell, this will not work either.

If there is any advice you can provide in regards to how this should be structured, it would help me greatly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that you are getting stuck because neither mongo (nor by extension mongoose) provides the ability to concisely express relational data.  Is there any reason you are not using a relational database?

Comment: Hi @Jonah. I am using mongoDb/mongoose because I am attempting to learn the mean stack. And in regards to relationships, I am positive that it is in fact possible to do what I am requesting using DBrefs, or am I wrong?

Comment: You're structuring your data as if it were relational though - have you consider just embedding groups and comments inside post?  You've got 16MB of space.

Comment: @JonahWilliams yes I have, which is what I am currently leaning towards. My main concern doing that is how I might reference it later. I would want to pull all the posts that are inside of a certain group, and by embedding the groups within the post, I am struggling on how I would make that database call. Could you provide insight on that?

Comment: @JoshuaL.: DBRefs are just glorified object ids. They do not facilitate queries in any way. They're useful when object can reference different types of objects in the same field (for example post has content and this content can be video, image, text, etc.). As far as I can see from schema above, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to embed your groups and comment schemas inside of your post document.  For example,

```
var GroupSchema = Schema({
    name: String, 
    created: { type:Date, default: Date.now },
});

var CommentSchema = Schema({
    text: String,
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});


var PostSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    ...,
    postedBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    comments: [CommentSchema] 
    groups: [GroupSchema]
});
```

Now, if you are looking for posts with a particular group, you can build a query as follows.  You can build more complicated queries than this however.

```
Post.elemMatch("groups", {name: {$in: ["group1", "group2"]}}).then(...)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your answer. I do have one follow up question. How might the query look when pulling a list of all groups? This would need to be a list of all the unique groups, within multiple posts, that belong to a specific user.

Comment: if that is the more common query, I suggest embedding the groups within the user as well.  Even though it seems like unnecessary duplication, document databases are really all about denormalized data.

Comment: Hello, that does seem like a good idea. I would need a way to push the group data when saved from the post.group to the user.group. This way data is in sync. Would you know how to do this? Or another way of keeping the groups in sync?

Comment: I am thinking something as simple as `user.groups.push(post.group);
user.save(callback);`